# cmake flags for compiler test only

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to specify some compiler/linker flags that will be used for the cmake compiler test only (i.e, the actual project will use a different set of flags)?
For example, I need to compile the main project with the -mcpu=native option while not using this option for the test program.
Alternatively, is there a way to check if cmake is compiling the test program and then define the compile flags based on this condition?
Thanks

Comment: Do we talk about [`try_compile()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html) here (which is also used for the first compiler checks)? Then yes, you can check global property [`IN_TRY_COMPILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/IN_TRY_COMPILE.html). I'm using this inside my toolchain files to see if CMake is currently running some compiler checks. Or you can use your own try compile config via [`CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_CONFIGURATION.html).